# VoIP only for two phones

Tags: voip

I would like to connect only two IP phones to talk each other (I have no idea about IP telephony). Is it possible without using a PBX? I mean, just connecting IP phone to IP phone with a straight/crossover cable.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can connect 2 IP phones same network (LAN and it should not be exposed to the internet because you'll get [ghost calls](https://telzio.com/support/ghost-calls)) and call the other phone by dialing its local IP address, even when the phone does not have a normal phone account.

Here you can see screenshots from such a call. This is a Yealink T28p IP phone not connected to a PBX and no account on it.

[image: test]

Dialing the IP address of the other phone (a Yealink T26, but I'm doing the same thing with other manufacturer phones', Grandstream to name one.). The Star key is used for the dot.
[image]

Calling...
[image]

And Speaking just like a normal call:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  Something needs to provide firmware for download, initial configuration and some kind of control plane to allow the phones to find one another and negotiate codecs and such.  A basic installation of Asterix or Call Manager Express on a router would be a good place to start.

Comment: This is not true. @Yisroel Tech answer is correct. You can make a call via ip or DNS names.